# How do you copy and move multiple numerical files in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, filesystem, copy

I have a sequence of timelapse files on my Raspberry Pi that I am trying to copy across to a memory card.  I have to split the move into two batches (source folder is twice the size of the destination folder).  Here is the script that I have been working (all day!).  I still can't get it to run.

```
cp -v /home/pi/timelapse   "201712140[20331-45246] {} /media/pi/FC33-7BFB1/timelapse
```

The source folder files sequence at 15sec increments from `20171214020331` - `20171214045246`.

Comment: Split it into batches how?

Comment: That command has a dangling quote.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to match a range of numbers, from 20331 to 45246, but the square bracket glob syntax is for a char set, not a range.

Comment: You seem to be asking a "[Give me a fish question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2686/how-should-you-respond-to-give-me-a-fish-rtfm-questions)". Both you and those who find your question later would be best served by a "How to Fish answer", this is why you have not had your code written for you. A useful set of search terms is [bash brace expansion](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=bash+Brace+expansion&t=canonical&ia=web)

Comment: If it's a one-off task, use a file manager such as Midnight Commander. Highlight the files by tapping on Insert, and copy with F5.

Answer (score 2):

The cp command takes one or more source files followed by a destination.  If there are multiple source files (as in your case) the destination must be a directory (where the files will all be copied to).  As per the comment, you are misusing the square brackets.  I don't know what the curly braces will do, but highly likely not what you want.
Assuming your first source file is /home/pi/timelapse/20171214020331, that the filenames don't contain spaces, and that the destination directory /media/pi/FC33-7BFB1/timelapse already exists, try

```
cp /home/pi/timelapse/201712140[23]* /media/pi/FC33-7BFB1/timelapse/
```

If that copies all files starting 2017121402 and 2017121403 you can move the next set using [45] etc.  That's a bit cumbersome, but will get you started on your voyage of discovery...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to copy file, finding by `regex` in a range

```
for file in 201712140*
do
    matched="$(echo "$file" | grep -oP '(?<=201712140)([^.]+)')"
    if [[ $matched -ge 20331 && $matched -le 45246 ]]; then
        cp -v $file /your/location
    fi
done
```

Just run this script in your source directory. Save it in a file `xyz.sh`
and run `bash xyz.sh`